# Migration of data from slave to master in Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, database-replication, redis-cluster

I'm currently exploring Redis cluster. I've started 6 instances on 3 physical servers(3 master and 3 slaves) with persistence enabled.

I've noticed that when I kill one of the master instances then it's slave is promoted to master after some time. However, it **`remains as master`** even when I start the killed instance.

Since, Redis does asynchronous replication, therefore, I was thinking of a scenario where the master, immediately after flushing the data is killed i.e. **`it wasn't able to replicate that data`**.

> Will this data get replicated to the new master(initially slave), once
>   the instance comes back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. If the master haven't replicate data to slave, the data will be lost. When the old master recovers, it will be become a slave of some other node based on [some rules](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#how-nodes-rejoin-the-cluster). Then the old master will replicate data from its new master.